# Issue with entering password on Google login page

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm new to node/puppeteer I'm having an issue clicking the next button to add int a password into a Google login form. I can add the email and click the next button for the email. I can also add in the password. I'm just not able to click the next button to get it to work I've looked online and tried await page.waitForNavigation(); but this didn't help. What am I missing?

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3542.0 Safari/537.36');
    // Set up Broswer

    await page.goto(CREDS.site);
    await page.waitForNavigation();
    await page.click('#identifierId');
    await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.username, { delay: 5 });
    await page.click('#identifierNext');
    // Go to website click email field, type in email, click next

    await page.waitForNavigation();

    await page.waitForSelector('#password input[type="password"]', { visible: true });
    await page.type('#password input[type="password"]', CREDS.password, { delay: 5 });
    await page.waitForNavigation();
    await page.click('#passwordNext');
    // wait for next page type in password click next
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing to be able to click the next button for the password. It works fine for the email. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are there JavaScript errors? "Doesn't work" really isn't enough to go on here.

Comment: I get no errors. It just does not click the next button on the password page. It adds in the email, clicks next, adds the password then stays on that page (even thought i have await page.click('#passwordNext');) the only error i get is a timeout. I think that's due to it not going to the next page. @tadman

Comment: I figured it out. page.waitForNavigation(); might not be the best use here. I tried page.waitForSelector and was able to get it to work! Thanks :)

Comment: You can try this workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48773255/trouble-logging-in-to-google-with-headless-chrome-puppeteer/55203273#55203273

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. page.waitForNavigation(); might not be the best use here. I tried page.waitForSelector and was able to get it to work! Thanks :)